# Optimal Drive Configuration and Cache Setup for TrueNAS running media server and personal files

Tags: hard-drive, storage, truenas

I'm new to TrueNAS and seeking advice on the optimal setup for my system.

I've built my system with the following specifications:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3400G CPU
- 16GB RAM
- 3x 3TB WD Red (I can install an additional 3TB WD Red drive in the future)
- 2x 2TB WD Red,
- 512GB m.2. SSD for TrueNAS.

My goal is to host personal files and a media collection for Jellyfin/Plex. Redundancy is crucial for personal files (I want to maximize this redundancy), but less so for the media collection since I always have physical copies of this.

What is the best way to configure my drives? My current idea is to use the three 3TB drives in a RAIDZ1 setup and host all my files on these drives (if I get a fourth 3TB drive, I might make this RAIDZ2), and use the 2TB drives in a mirror configuration to which I make a daily backup of my personal files.

I'm also considering an additional SSD on which I install TrueNAS, so that I can repurpose the m.2. SSD as cache (L2ARC) for the 3x3TB pool, is this a good idea?

Any insights appreciated, including other suggestions.

Comment: TrueNAS questions really should be asked on the [TrueNAS forum](https://www.truenas.com/community/) because of it's highly specialized nature, as most users on here aren't going to be able to help. Most of the info you're looking for has been covered on the forum, so forum search will be a valuable tool =] iXsystems also provides a wealth of knowledge under [Documentation](https://www.truenas.com/docs/), such as the [Core man pages](https://www.truenas.com/docs/core/) and [references](https://www.truenas.com/docs/references/) section ([L2ARC](https://www.truenas.com/docs/references/l2arc/))